# String not getting stored in vector?

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string n, m;
    vector <string> dingdong;

    cin >> n;
    dingdong.push_back(n);
    cin >> m;
    dingdong.push_back(m);

    for (int i = 0; i <2; i ++) {
        cout << dingdong[i];
    }


    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program and I input "hay sombody there" and hit enter. The program prints "haysombody." So I figured if I increase 'i' to 3 the program will print "haysombodythere" but no, main just crashes. why is this happening and how do I make it so that the entire strings (including the spaces) get stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"why is this happening and how do I make it so that the entire strings (including the spaces) get stored?"*

To get more than a single word from the input you should use

```
std::getline(cin,n);
```

instead of

```
std::cin >> n;
```

White spaces are used as delimiters by default, so each call of `std::istream`'s `operator>>` will just store the text read up to the next white space character.

---

See a fully fixed version of your program [here](http://ideone.com/hy3Yy0) please.

---

Also if you really want to read into the `vector` word by word, you use a loop doing so

```
string word;
vector <string> dingdong;
while(cin >> word) {
    if(word.empty) {
        break;
    }
    dingdong.push_back(word);
}
```

and print out like

```
for (int i = 0; i < dingdong.size(); ++i) {
    cout << dingdong[i];
}
```

Comment: how would I go about it if I was to pass the string 'word' into a class function.

I have:


string aboutwhat;
cout << "Enter subject: " << endl;
getline(cin, aboutwhat);
person.changeSubject(aboutwhat);
cout << person.getSubject();

the program just prints "Enter subject" and ends the program.

Comment: @Jahaha That's a different question. You ask another one. But in general you have some function signature like `void foo(const std::string& word);`, or `void foo(std::string& word)`; depends if you need to change the parameter or not.